# ScrollViews of several UITableView or Horizontal UITableView with side by side sections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I want to have something like this :

http://d.pr/i/yLKd

I don't know if the best solution (easiest, most intelligent and efficient) is to make an UIScrollView with several UITableView side by side. Or to make an horizontal UITableView with diferents sections (which will be 'Category' here).

All my datas come from Core Data.

EDIT : TableView in a TableView ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer you to use one tableview with different sections. if you choice another way may have problem with touch detecting between UITableView and UIScrollView

Comment: Do you know some tools that I could use to do it ?

Comment: Creating secrion on tableview is very simple. you can use storyboard if your app is for ios 5 and greater.

Comment: I'm not worry about this, it's more about having verticals sections in an horizontal TableView.